# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:

Tags: apex, trigger, web2lead

This Trigger is on lead (Before Insert, Before Update) and it errors (System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object). I'm getting this error when i'm posting "Web to Lead". However i do have the right ORG iD and Record type id included on the xml file:

> ```
> <input type=hidden name="oid" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
> <input type=hidden name="recordType" id="recordType" value="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz">
> ```

```
trigger IAAILeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update){
//BEGIN: S-444340 T-561808 - Process only IAA Remarketing Recordtype data
    Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

    //Looks up the branches based on the Lead PostalCode
    if(trigger.isBefore){

        for(Lead ld : trigger.new){            
         if (rt_map.get(ld.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('IAA Remarketing') )

              if( trigger.isInsert || 
                  (trigger.isUpdate && ld.Branch__c == null) ||
                  (trigger.isUpdate && ld.PostalCode != trigger.oldMap.get(ld.id).PostalCode)
              ){
                  leads.add(ld);
              }

         }    
      }        
        //Only check the leads that are in the lead list and NOT the full trigger.new list
        if(!leads.isEmpty()){
            LeadController.GetLeadBranches(leads);  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This saves? Where is `leads`?

Comment: On a BeforeInsert, there is NO Lead ID. There's also No Oldmap either. What you're doing will only work for a BeforeUpdate.

Comment: Thanks #crmprogdev that answers the question and I have fixed it by adding if statement if(ld.ID != null).

Comment: @crmprogdev, can you convert your response into an answer so templar can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what crmprogdev was saying, he was saying you don't have access to `ld.id` or the `oldMap` in the `before insert` context.  We don't know what GetLeadBranches is doing but if you need the `IDs` you need to change it to `after insert`..

By putting `if(ld.ID != null){}` you're completely negating the `before insert` part of this trigger, but considering your checking the `oldMap` It appears that you only care about `updates` so you can just trash the `insert` context entirely.

```
Trigger IAAILeadTrigger on Lead (before update)
{

Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
//Looks up the branches based on the Lead PostalCode
for(Lead ld : Trigger.new)
{            
    if (rt_map.containsKey(ld.recordTypeID) && 
        rt_map.get(ld.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('IAA Remarketing') )
    {
      if(Trigger.isInsert || 
          (Trigger.isUpdate && ld.Branch__c == null) ||
          (Trigger.isUpdate && ld.PostalCode != Trigger.oldMap.get(ld.ID).PostalCode)
      )
          {
              leadList.add(ld);
          }
    }    
}        
//Only check the leads that are in the lead list and NOT the full 
if(!leadList.isEmpty()){
    LeadController.GetLeadBranches(leadList);  
  }
}
```